# Where is this variable coming from in this react script

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm starting out looking at react, I've seen a good example here https://scotch.io/tutorials/learning-react-getting-started-and-concepts
however I'm not sure where 'item' is coming from, it doesn't appear to be declared anywhere. I've highlighted item in the code below.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var List = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <ul>
      {
        this.props.items.map(function(**item**) {
          return <li key=**{item}>{item}**</li>
        })
       }
      </ul>
    )  
  }
});

var FilteredList = React.createClass({
  filterList: function(event){
    var updatedList = this.state.initialItems;
    updatedList = updatedList.filter(function(**item**){
      return **item**.toLowerCase().search(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
    this.setState({items: updatedList});
  },
  getInitialState: function(){
     return {
       initialItems: [
         "Apples",
         "Broccoli",
         "Chicken",
         "Duck",
         "Eggs",
         "Fish",
         "Granola",
         "Hash Browns"
       ],
       items: []
     }
  },
  componentWillMount: function(){
    this.setState({items: this.state.initialItems})
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className="filter-list">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={this.filterList}/>
      <List items={this.state.items}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<FilteredList/>, document.getElementById('mount-point'));
```

Comment: Assuming you mean the `function(item)` -- this is just the first parameter passed into array collection functions (map, filter, reduce, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`updatedList` is an array.

Array.filter takes a function as an argument that will be passed in a variable. They are using `item` as that variable name.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: sorry for the obvious questions but I'm still confused. Where is item parameter being called and what value is passed into it?